# can workflow activity be used as a condition in business rules?

Tags: servicenow

When I try to use the condition

`current.wf_activity.name.toString() == "xxxx"` it's not triggering the Business rule.

When I try displaying it using `gs.addInfoMessage(current.wf_activity.name.toString());` it displays 'xxxx'.

It's also observed that for specific types of workflow the BusinessRule triggers while for others it's not. I have already tried without `toString()` method which is also not working.

Using `getDisplayValue()` also doesnt works

Can someone site a good example for using workflow activity in business rule conditions?

Comment: when i tried changing the condition `current.wf_activity.name.indexOf('xx')>=0)` it worked.! But still no idea why '==' din't work though.!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible your `wf_activity` isn't actually set at the time the business rule runs. You may try increasing the order of your business rule to something over 1000 (so it runs after engines) or changing it from a "before" to an "after" rule.

If that doesn't work, remove the condition from the BR and log the current value and comparison result:

```
gs.log("MYDEBUG: current.wf_activity.name=[" + current.wf_activity.name + "]);
gs.log("MYDEBUG: comparison?=" + (current.wf_activity.name.toString() == "xxxx"));
```

Comment: How is it possible for the value to be displayed in the infomessage if 
the `wf_activity` is not set?

Comment: When you issue an insert/update against a particular record, it runs through a series of engines that exercise logic against the record. Business Rules are one such engine, Workflow is another engine. Business rules with an order less than 1000 run *before* the workflow engine, so it's possible that the wf_activity is set in the workflow engine *after* your business rule but *before* your info message is added. So, if your infoMessage is being added *in* the business rule in question, it's diagnostically equivalent to what I'm suggesting.